# Single handler for ReactJS onClick and onKeyDown events for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add `onKeyPress` handlers to my application to make it `a11y`-compliant. I have some interactive `<div />` elements, where it is presenting a problem.

I have the following event handlers to I want to fire on click.

```
const handleViewInfoClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> | KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
  event.preventDefault();
  onProfileClick();
  window.open(withConfig(ConfigEnum.PROPERTY_PROFILE_URL, { propertyID: communityId }), '_blank');
};
```

I am using the above hanlder as:

```
<div
  className={classes.community_name}
  onClick={handleViewInfoClick}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      handleViewInfoClick(e);
    }
  }}
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
>
```

It results in typescript errors.

If I declare `event` as `(event: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent)`, typescript complaints that `handleViewInfoClick(e)` is getting a wrong type for an argument. If I declare `KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>`, the `handleViewInfoClick(e)` is not raising errors. However, typescript complaints that `Type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>' is not generic`.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With React handlers, you should use the event typings from React, not from the DOM:

```
const handleViewInfoClick = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
```

You could also use

```
const handleViewInfoClick = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
```

because both KeyboardEvent and MouseEvent inherit from SyntheticEvent, and all you care about is being able to call `preventDefault` on it, which SyntheticEvent has.